# could not find mobile redirect link for old version php zend framework

Tags: php, css, zend-framework

My website could not run in mobile. Previous version goes with redirect link `/m/` for mobile view (www.example.com/m/) when we call the site on mobile but I don't want to redirect `/m/` in my new version so I delete `/m/` in some of my codings and made the responsive website but it doesn't work responsively.

Here's some of my codings from `Appbase.php`:

```
class Zend_Controller_Appbase extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    const SITE_TYPE_PC = 1;
    const SITE_TYPE_MOBILE = 2;

    protected function _getStoreUrl($protocol = 'http://', $siteType = 0)
    {
        $host = $this->getRequest()->getHttpHost();
        $baseUrl = $this->getFrontController()->getBaseUrl();

        switch ($siteType)
        {
            case self::SITE_TYPE_PC:
                $baseUrl = preg_replace("@^/m@", "", $baseUrl);
                break;
            case self::SITE_TYPE_MOBILE:
                $baseUrl = preg_replace("@^/m@", "", $baseUrl);
                break;
            default:
        }

        return $protocol . $host . $baseUrl . '/';
    }
}
```

Comment: It's PHP code, and it's not related to responsive design. Explain "doesn't work responsively".

Comment: This php link I shown above is removing the redirect link /m/. It should work well after I have removed the redirect link in there. Nothing wrong with the mobile responsive css because I made a testing in http://mobiletest.me/ and check with responsive tester on chrome. The problem I am facing is that even after I removed the redirect link the website doesn't go with mobile responsive which i captured @media(max-width: 767px) and it shows @media(min-width: 1200px) size.